# Can't delay plotting Google Map Markers in MeteroJS app

Tags: google-maps, meteor, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to replicate the animation of a marker following a route in MeteorJS following the approach @ https://duncan99.wordpress.com/2015/01/22/animated-paths-with-google-maps/. In Meteor, the trouble I am having is the coordinates that reside in a Mongo collection are served  up as being reactive. Because of this, my use of setInterval, setTimeout, or using packages such as Chronos are not working. My approach is simple to draw the route (which works fine), then place a marker at the first coordinate, delay, remove it and place a new marker at the next coord, repeat..., giving it the appearance of movement. Problem is I can't figure out why the delay approach is not working, rendering marker movement so fast it just shows up. Code below. Trust the CodeParser function works and vars are declared upfront. TIA.

```js
var apiKey = "------------";
var latValue = "------------";
var lngValue = "------------";
var MAP_ZOOM = "--";
var oldLatLng = "";
var oldUTC = 0;
var i = 0;

if (Meteor.isClient) {

Template.map.helpers({
 mapOptions: function() {
  if (GoogleMaps.loaded()) {
    return {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(latValue, lngValue),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      zoom: MAP_ZOOM  //USA view...but will zoom based on sync location
    };
  }
 }
});

Template.map.onCreated(function()
  {

  //load API
  GoogleMaps.load({ key:apiKey, libraries: 'geometry,places,visualization' });
  console.log("GoogleAPI loaded with key: " + apiKey);  

  //Prep API and insert initial dataset
  GoogleMaps.ready('map', function(map) {

  //check for and get NMEA coords from collection
  dataset = Coords.find({}, {sort: { order_id: 1}});

  //iterate through dataset and animate marker movement
  dataset.forEach(function (stat) {

      Tracker.autorun(function()
        {
        Chronos.liveUpdate(2000); //1 sec dlay between each marker movement

        //convert coords
        myLatLng = CoordParser(stat.lat, stat.lat_dir, stat.lon, stat.lon_dir);

        //place marker on path using coords
        if (oldLatLng != "" && myLatLng != oldLatLng && stat.utc_timestamp >= oldUTC) { //conditions for error checking

          if (i==0) {           //mark start with a marker if it is the first point

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatLng,
              icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
              map: map.instance,
              title: "start"
              });

              i++; //increase counter for logging test only

          } else {  //animate marker

            //remove last marker with timing delay to give appearance of movement
            marker.setMap(null);

            //draw next marker
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatLng,
              icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
              map: map.instance,
              title: stat._id
            });

          }
        } //end draw route

        //set old point for destination point next loop
        oldLatLng = myLatLng;
        oldUTC = stat.utc_timestamp;

        }); //end chronos delay

      });  //end for each point to move marker

   }); //end googlemap ready    

  }); //end on created

};
```

Comment: It looks like this has to do with the foreach. I'm guessing the timeouts are all starting (and finishing) at the same time. You should probably make this sequential somehow.

Comment: Update it looks like in the link you provided the steps are made sequential by multiplying the timeout with the iterator: 200 * i.

Comment: I've tried using setTimeout, setInterval and the Chronos package to delay the for/each loop execution to no luck. the screen is simply rendering the entire collection "dataset" without paying attention to the delay. Using Chronos results in the entire recordset looping infinitely...unfortunately the link I provided is a simple JS only sample that is not reactive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your timeouts/chronos thingies all run at the same time. If you multiply the timeout time by the index of the dataset item they should fire in sequence.

Code sample below is with Meteor.setTimeout but the same principle should apply to chronos I guess.

```js
  //iterate through dataset and animate marker movement
  dataset.forEach(function (stat,index) {
        Meteor.setTimeout(function(){
          //Use the console to see if we are stepping through the points
          console.log(stat);

          //YOUR MARKER MOVING CODE HERE

        },2000 * index);//HERE WE MULTIPLY THE TIMEOUT WITH THE INDEX
  });
```

When you look in the console of your browser you should see the coordinate objects come by one by one, not at the same time.

Your foreach loop doesn't wait for the timeout to finish, it just loops through all items very quickly (within a second). So the idea is to delay each move for the time you set plus the time of the previous moves.

Comment: It worked, appreciate the help! Amazing how a simple multiplier fixes 2 days of headaches...